# Angular - Is it possible to use a control's path instead of its name within nested reactive forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

To put it simply, when using nested reactive forms, is it possible to have something like this :

```html
<!-- DESIRED -->
<form [formGroup]="rootFormGroup">
  <custom-input formControlName="nestedFormGroup.someVariable"></custom-input>
</form>
```

Instead of this :

```html
<!-- CURRENT STATE -->
<form [formGroup]="rootFormGroup">
  <div formGroupName="nestedFormGroup">
    <custom-input formControlName="someVariable"></custom-input>
  </div>
</form>
```

A bit of context : our "custom inputs" require the full path to the control (as well as the `rootFormGroup`, although it's been left out of the snippet) in order to call some services such as :

- cross-validation with other variables in the root form.
- loading the label for the input
- for `<select>`-derived custom inputs, loading the options

We could change the latter two to use the name instead of the full path (as long as we do not use the same name twice in different nested groups), but the cross-validation uses `rootFormGroup.get(...)`, which in turns calls for the path.

Of course, it's possible to inject both (eg : `<custom-input path="nestedFormGroup.someVariable" formControlName="someVariable">`) but that's not terribly dry.

For the same reason, I'd like to avoid using the formControl directive (eg : `<custom-input path="nestedFormGroup.someVariable" [formControl]="rootFormGroup.get('nestedFormGroup.someVariable')">`)

If push comes to shove, I can probably manage with some vaguely recursive function to inspect any FormGroup/FormArray stemming from `rootFormGroup` in order to find a control with only its name (as opposed to its full path), but that is not entirely satisfying either.

Nothing critical here, but any help or comment is most definitely welcome !

Comment: could you show your custom-input component?

Comment: @krutkowski86 our custom inputs are built upon our somewhat complex (but recurrent) use cases. It would take some time to strip them down to a minimal usable component. In case you need references to implement your own custom input, you can use this really good article by Pascal Precht : https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html